# what is elastic search DSL equivalent of WHERE status = 'DONE' AND badgeId IN ( 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3' )

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write the elastic search DSL query equivalent of the following :

`SELECT * FROM awards WHERE status='DONE' AND badgeId IN ('ID1','ID2','ID3')`

Where `badgeId` is the type of product in the awards.
and `status` describes the status of the product in the awards.

the index map is as follows

```
{
    "awards": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "badgeId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "blockchainAwardId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "blockchainBadgeId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "creatorPermission": {
                        "properties": {
                            "isPublic": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "dbCreateTime": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "dbUpdateTime": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "evidence": {
                        "properties": {
                            "audience": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "genre": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "link": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "narrative": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "exists": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "isAwarded": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isDeleted": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isRevoked": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "orgId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "recipientName": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "uid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "3",
                "provided_name": "awards",
                "creation_date": "1557735146607",
                "store": {
                    "type": "niofs"
                },
                "unassigned": {
                    "node_left": {
                        "delayed_timeout": "5m"
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "2",
                "uuid": "mXkj_6BkQwOwIiAsNiHBXQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6020299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
POST collection/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { 
          "term" : {"status.keyword": "DONE" }
        },
        { 
          "terms" : {"badgeId.keyword": ["TYPE_1", "TYPE_2", "TYPE_3"] }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-term-filter.html The term filter has been replaced by the Term Query.

Comment: Believe me, the above query is up to date to the latest and greatest. You can use it safely. What has been deprecated is `query/filter` not [`query/bool/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html) which is perfectly ok

Comment: it returns nothing for some reason

Comment: I might know why. Can you show your index mapping? `GET collection`

Comment: I updated the question . I was away from the computer for sometime sry for that

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: Cool, glad we made it!